# Are there any difficulties to transition from nginx 1.18 to 1.20.x? asking, Since it not a typical upgrade

Tags: nginx, upgrade, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to upgrade nginx to >= 1.20 for an ubuntu server 20.04. but the catch is currently apt-get update only gets you to 1.18.x where I am already at.

Here's my question:

1. How do I effectively install the latest version?
2. What files should I make sure to backup and restore once the installation is done?
3. What can help me transition my sites and config easily on the latest version of nginx?

I am new to the atypical upgrade mechanism for nginx and wanted to confirm if there is something I need to be worried about.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: does this guide help you? https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-upgrade-latest-nginx-mainline-stable-on-ubuntu-20-04/